# Loading JSON object with $.getJSON on a button click

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to load a JSON Object that looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Max",
    "age" : "22"
     }
```

when pressing a button on the page.

I've searched through stackoverflow and the documentation, but didn't really find something that helped or worked out yet. Could anyone explain in details on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("test.json", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button>Klick mich!</button>

    <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit: Okay, so in Firefox it actually works and shows the name and age. I was using Chrome and it didn't load anything.

Comment: Where is the json stored _on your server_?

Comment: The index.html and the test.json are both in a folder on the Desktop.

Comment: test with Firefox and Firebug network manager, if the json file is really called or there is a error like 404

Comment: Do you *just* open the `index.html` file, or do you actually serve this through http?

Comment: You can't load the file without an server. Have a look at nodejs' simple http-server for example

Comment: @YingYang in Firefox it actually works and shows the name and age after clicking the Button. Just doesn't seem to work with Chrome. Strange.

Comment: dont use getJSON, its not working with chrome for example. always use $.ajax with produces json. getJson is not working properly on smartphones, too. Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `...both in a folder on the Desktop` that's your issue. You cannot make AJAX requests to the local file system in well-secured browsers. You need to run on a server instead. You can easily install XAMPP or IIS if you Google them.

Comment: @YingYang `$.getJSON` works fine with Chrome and smart phones  when used correctly, what you stated is completely false.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I had problems using getJson in the past. With different browsers. With older Android versions for example. Because of the implementation of getJson Chome is thinking its an CrossDomain. (I think thats what you meant, too) However it should work with $.ajax. I dont see a benefit for using getJson instead of $.ajax, either. You dont realy need a local webserver to programm HTML and Javascript, but it would be a benefit

Comment: You must have been doing something wrong then, as `$.getJSON` is just a shortcut to `$.ajax` - it calls it internally if you check the source: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.getJSON

Comment: Its possible i was doing something wrong. But maybe there are some default options differences, between $.ajax and $.get. All I remember, it was not working with every smartphone with getJson, but with $.ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install XAMPP and set up an Apache server and put the index.html and test.json files into the htdocs folder, so I could request the json object when clicking on the button.

Now it works as intended in every browser!